# Strange Email Validation request - should I worry about it?

Tags: validation, scam

I have a domain in .name zone registered in Germany. A couple of days ago I received an email, here is the English part of it:

> Dear customer *(the German text has my name instead of "customer" here)*,
>
> by the guidelines of the internet administrative organization ICANN we
>   are obliged to verify the correctness of the owner contacts in the
>   registrations of all generic TLD endings. We have to validate your
>   email address as the domain owner.
>
> We would, therefore, like to ask you to confirm the correctness of your
>   contact e-mail address by clicking on the following
>   link:
>
> https: //www. domainvalidierung.de /AStringOfRandomAlphaNumericalCharacters/
>
> In your case this validation is done, inter alia, for the following
>   domain: *my-domain.name*
>
> If you have additional domains with a generic domain ending with the
>   same email address for the domain owner then these domains will also
>   be automatically validated by the confirmation of the link above.
>
> Important Note: If you do not confirm your email address by 22.09.2018
>   all new domain registrations using this email address will be
>   disconnected in accordance with the ICANN policies until the email
>   address is confirmed. Such domains remain registered but are no longer
>   accessible. You can activate the domains by clicking the link above at
>   any time. No further data or other personal information is needed for
>   the validation.
>
> Contractual Basis: The validation of the registrant contact of a
>   domain for all generic TLDs is part of the ongoing efforts of ICANN to
>   improve the contact data quality of the domain owner. We are obliged
>   to implement these requirements of ICANN to be able to offer
>   registration services for all generic TLDs such as .COM, .INFO,
>   .BERLIN, .KOELN, .CLUB and .BIZ

I did not start any domain transfer. 
The email was sent to my email which was used for the domain registration, my real name is used (but I think both could be found in whois entry).

What seems suspicious to me:

- "www.domainvalidierung.de/" is blank.
- I have two other domains for which I didn't receive such an email.

Is this "validation" legit? Can I ignore it? Should I ignore it?

Comment: Why don't you check with the registrar of your domain?

Comment: This *type* of e-mail is quite common. Registrars have to check that contact addresses are indeed still valid. Whether this one actually *is* is a different matter. It would make sense for the e-mail to send you to your registrar's domain/site rather than an unrelated domain, but it's difficult to know. You may might to check with your registrar whether it is legitimate or not.

Answer (score 1):

Under ICANN's Whois Data Reminder Policy accredited registrars will revalidate contact information yearly - did you by any chance register this domain on 22/09/2017?

Aside from this, it may be a routine validation to ensure the Whois data is correct or it may be in response to a complaint regarding the current data.

There are a number of [ICANN policies](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/contact-verification-2013-05-03-en) which registrars are obliged to follow which would explain this. My only word of caution is to ensure this came from a trusted source.

Comment: Is the policy new? I registered the domain several years ago and this is the first time I received such an email? And I have two another domains (different registrar) for about 10 years now, there was never such an email about them either.

Comment: Maybe it's a dispute over the Whois data that promoted it? Could also potentially be an internal revalidation the company is going through. There are a number of reasons for it but it does not appear to be anything malicious.
I'm sure if you reached out to them they could shed some light.

Comment: I'm waiting for a registrar's response.